# ArrayList and sorting method for names

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I am almost done with this project. I need help figuring out why it does not pause after asking for the last name before it asks for the first name. I also keep getting an error when I try to add a new Comparator to sort by score.

```
package student.scores;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;




public class StudentScores{


   public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Student Scores Application.");

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of students: ");
int numStudents = input.nextInt();
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter Student Last Name: ");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Student First Name: ");
    String firstName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Student Score: ");
    int score = input.nextInt();
    students.add(new Student(lastName, firstName, score));
}
Collections.sort(students);
System.out.println("Students in alphabetical order");
for (Student s : students) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
Collections.sort(students, new Comparator() {});
System.out.println("Students by score");
for (Student s : students) {
    System.out.println(s);
```

}

```
static class Student implements Comparable<Student>
```

{

```
   private  String lastName;
   private String firstName;
   private int scores;

    public Student (String lastName, String firstName, int score)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.scores = score;
    }

    public int getScores()
    {
        return scores;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student s)
    {
       if (s.lastName.equals(lastName))
       {
           return firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(s.firstName);
       }
      return lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(s.lastName);
    }

    static class StudentScoreComparator implements Comparator<Student>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2)
        {
            return (Integer.valueOf(o1.getScores())).compareTo(o2.getScores());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
           return String.format("%s %s %d", firstName, lastName, scores);
    }
```

}
}

Comment: I don't want to be splitting hairs here but you indicated the program "**stores the results in an array**" and you are using an ArrayList. Is this OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I added an import for the Comparable method. I also changed it to add a line between the output.

```
package student.scores;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import student.scores.StudentScores.Student.StudentScoreComparator;




public class StudentScores{


   public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Welcome to the Student Scores Application.");

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of students: ");
int numStudents = input.nextInt();

List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

int counter = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
    int studentNum = counter++;
    System.out.println("\nStudent " + studentNum);
    System.out.println("Enter Student Last Name: ");
    String lastName = input.next();

    System.out.println("Enter Student First Name: ");
    String firstName = input.next();


    System.out.println("Enter Student Score: ");
    int score = input.nextInt();
    students.add(new Student(lastName, firstName, score));
}
Collections.sort(students);
System.out.println("Students in alphabetical order: ");
for (Student s : students) {
    System.out.println(s);       
}
System.out.println();

Collections.sort(students, new StudentScoreComparator());
System.out.println("Students by score:");
for (Student s : students) {
    System.out.println(s);
```

}
   }

```
static class Student implements Comparable<Student>
```

{

```
   private  String lastName;
   private String firstName;
   private int scores;

    public Student (String lastName, String firstName, int score)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.scores = score;
    }

    public int getScores()
    {
        return scores;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student s)
    {
       if (s.lastName.equals(lastName))
       {
           return firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(s.firstName);
       }
      return lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(s.lastName);
    }

    static class StudentScoreComparator implements Comparator<Student>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2)
        {
            return (Integer.valueOf(o1.getScores())).compareTo(o2.getScores());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
           return String.format("%s %s %d", firstName, lastName, scores);
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest approach for also sorting by `score` is to add a second class that implements [`Comparator<Student>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) like

```
static class StudentScoreComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return (Integer.valueOf(o1.getScores())).compareTo(o2.getScores());
    }
}
```

Then you can pass an instance of that `Comparator` to the sort methods, and sort by score.

**Edit**

Then I would add a `toString()` to `Student` like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s %s %d", firstName, lastName, scores);
}
```

**Edit 2**

I think your `main()` was supposed to look like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Student Scores Application.");

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of students: ");
    int numStudents = input.nextInt();
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Student Last Name: ");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Student First Name: ");
        String firstName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Student Score: ");
        int score = input.nextInt();
        students.add(new Student(lastName, firstName, score));
    }
    Collections.sort(students);
    System.out.println("Students in alphabetical order");
    for (Student s : students) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    Collections.sort(students, new StudentScoreComparator());
    System.out.println("Students by score");
    for (Student s : students) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I will try adding that.

Comment: @LauraBullard Edited. The code you posted seems to sort by name(s). The `Comparator` will allow you to sort by score. Adding a `toString()` to `Student` you can simply iterate your sorted array or list and print each `Student`.

Comment: Frisch      I added the toString to the bottom under comparable. Is that where it should be? Also what should I do next? I have been stuck on how to finish this program. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @LauraBullard The toString() should be a method in `Student`. And I took another look at your main() method. You weren't storing anything as a `Student`.

Comment: @LauraBullard are you sure this assignment allows you to use Java Collections or is the point of the assignment to employ a sorting algorithm taught in class?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch  My code is working perfect to sort by score now thank you. I just need to have an option to sort by alphabetical also. Do you have any advice on what I should add for that? i ADDED MY UPDATED CODE AT THE TOP.

Comment: It looks like it sorts alphabetical first to me `System.out.println("Students in alphabetical order");`. Your latest edit is exactly my code. What isn't working? I see two `Collections.sort(students);`. One should be passing a `Comparator` instance.

Comment: @ElliottFrish  It is giving me an error when I put the comparator in the second one. It wants me to put something in the parentheses after StudentScoreComparator.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not using the Student class at all.  You need to be capturing the first name, last name, and score of each `Student` and storing the entry in an array of `Student` objects.

```
System.out.print("Enter student's first name: ");
String fname = input.next(); // Since names should not have white spaces, use next() instead of nextLine()

System.out.print("Enter student's last name: ");
String lname = input.next();

System.out.print("Enter student's score");
int score = input.next();

record[i] = new Student(fname, lname, score);
```

The code snippet above should be inside your loop.  Each iteration you are capturing a student's full name and score, and adding a new instance of `Student` inside your `Student` array.  The way I understood your assignment, each Student object represents a record.  The array can (and will) have multiple entries for a particular student, but not necessarily in order.  The sorting helps with printing out all records for the same student one after the other.  For example, index 0 of the array could be for "Joe Smith" while index 1 could be for "Anne Johnson". When sorted, all of the records for Anne Johnson should be listed first, then Joe Smith's records.

To sort by name, you need to compare the current index to the next, if there is one to compare. First, you must grab the last name and compare them. If they are equal, grab the first name. If they are equal, assume they (the records) are for the same student (and you can decide at that point to grab the score to sort by score). If the names are different, the records are for different students so you must execute sorting.  I am sure this is a school assignment, so use one of the sorting algorithms taught in class (maybe bubble sort) and sort the array.  Most likely, you will need multiple passes for the array to be fully sorted by name and scores.